# WordPress: Parent category -> Child categories -> Posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to build a query to a custom record type that would eventually output a category, and then all posts from that category. However, there is a point with categories with hierarchy. For such categories, I would like to display the parent category once, and not every time. So, I have this code:

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query([
    'post_type'            => 'afdigit',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'orderby'            => 'none',
]);
if ($query->have_posts()) { ?>
    <div class="cat">
        <?php $q = array();

        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            $a = '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';

            $top_term = get_top_term('afd-cats');
            $b = '<a href="' . get_category_link($top_term) . '">' . $top_term->name . '</a>';

            $categories = get_the_terms($post_id, 'afd-cats');

            foreach ($categories as $key => $category) {
                $c = '<a href="' . get_category_link($category) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>';
            }

            if ($top_term->term_id == $category->term_id) {
                $b;
            } else {
                $b = '<div class="top term_">' . $b . '</div>';
                $b .= '<div class="child">' . $c . '</div>';
            }

            $q[$b][] = $a;
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();

        foreach ($q as $key => $values) {
            echo '<div class="term">';
            echo $key;
            echo '<ul class="posts">';
            foreach ($values as $value) {
                echo '<li class="post">' . $value . '</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul></div>';
        } ?>
    </div>
<?php }
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

In function `get_top_term()`, I get the parent category if it exists.

```
function get_top_term($taxonomy, $post_id = 0)
{

    isset($post_id->ID) && $post_id = $post_id->ID;
    !$post_id && $post_id = get_the_ID();

    $terms = get_the_terms($post_id, $taxonomy);

    if (!$terms || is_wp_error($terms)) {
        return $terms;
    }

    $term = array_shift($terms);

    $parent_id = $term->parent;
    while ($parent_id) {
        $term = get_term_by('id', $parent_id, $term->taxonomy);
        $parent_id = $term->parent;
    }

    return $term;
}
```

Here I get almost what I need, namely:

```
Category 1
    Post
    Post
    Post

Category 2
    Post
    Post
    Post

Parent category 1
  Child category 1
    Post
    Post
    Post

Parent category 1
  Child category 2
    Post
    Post
    Post

Category 3
    Post
    Post
    Post
```

However, I would like to exclude repetitions of parent category so that it turns out like this:

```
Category 1
    Post
    Post
    Post

Category 2
    Post
    Post
    Post

Parent category 1
  Child category 1
    Post
    Post
    Post

  Child category 2
    Post
    Post
    Post

Category 3
    Post
    Post
    Post
```

Unfortunately, I have too little knowledge of php. I hope for your help both in solving the first question, and perhaps with advice on how to improve this code. Thanks)

Comment: Just IMHO- the style of those first couple of lines in `get_top_term` are terrible.

Comment: @NigelRen Yes, I feel it, but I can't do it better)))